# How to filter object-array with duplicated items name based on conditions in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have an object array with duplicated object properties value for some objects and I need to filter it according to some object properties conditions

I have something similar to the following code:

Model:

```swift
struct MyObject {
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var times: Int
    var value: Double
}
```

Array:

```swift
Let objectArray = [
            MyObject(name: “Obj1”, id: “123”, times: 1, value: 3.0),
            MyObject(name: “Obj2”, id: “456”, times: 1, value: 2.3),
            MyObject(name: “Obj3”, id: “789”, times: 1, value: 1.0),
            MyObject(name: “Obj2”, id: “456”, times: 2, value: 3.3),
            MyObject(name: “Obj2”, id: “456”, times: 3, value: 4.7),
            MyObject(name: “Obj4”, id: “212”, times: 1, value: 2.4)
        ]
```

I have implemented an extension `Array` function to remove the duplicated items in array but it's not enough on this case:

```swift
func filterDuplicate<T>(_ keyValue:(Element)->T) -> [Element] {
      var uniqueKeys = Set<String>()
      return filter{ uniqueKeys.insert("\(keyValue($0))").inserted }
   }
```

I need to filter `objectArray` to obtain an array without duplicated objects with the condition to maintain the highest value for times property, that means, the final result should be:

Expected result:

```swift
filteredObjectArray =  [
            MyObject(name: “Obj1”, id: “123”, times: 1, value: 3.0),
            MyObject(name: “Obj3”, id: “789”, times: 1, value: 1.0),
            MyObject(name: “Obj2”, id: “456”, times: 3, value: 4.7),
            MyObject(name: “Obj4”, id: “212”, times: 1, value: 2.4)
        ]
```

With `Obj2` repeated item filtered by `times` property = `3`

Comment: Ideally Set are different from Array in the sense that items are unique and not sortable. Maybe you can try to implement the Equatable protocol in your “MyObject” so that the ‘==‘ comparison will compare the ‘id’ properties. I assume that then Set will do the job for you of trimming out duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using reduce(into:) to filter out the unique objects

```
let uniqueAndHighest = objectArray.reduce(into: [MyObject]()) { array, object in
    if let index = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == object.id }) {
        if array[index].times < object.times {
            array[index] = object
        }
    } else {
        array.append(object)
    }
}
```

and an alternative solution using Dictionary(grouping:)

```
let uniqueAndHighest = Dictionary(grouping: objectArray) {$0.id}
    .values
    .compactMap { $0.max {$0.times < $1.times}}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works perfectly for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce in this case:

```
    let resultArray = objectArray.reduce([]) { (nextResult, obj) -> [MyObject] in
        var tempArray = nextResult
        if let existObj = tempArray.first(where: { $0.name == obj.name && $0.id == obj.id }) {
            if obj.times > existObj.times {
                tempArray.removeAll(where: { $0.name == existObj.name })
                tempArray.append(obj)
            }
        } else {
            tempArray.append(obj)
        }
        return tempArray
    }
```